# How can find out what features have activated when I create a site collection using a out of box site definition

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I plan to create  custom site using web template.I need to find out  what features have activated when I create a site collection using a out of box site definition.How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it out from the Site Definition file located at 14\Template\SiteTemplates. For each configuration of the site template there are "SiteFeatures" and "WebFeatures" elements which lists what features needs to be activated when a new site is created using that site template (and configuration). Remember that if those features depend on any other features which are hidden, they will also be automatically activated.

I believe you know how to locate the ONET.xml file for the out of the box site definition. If not, following PowerShell command will help you.

Get-SPWebTemplate | where { ( $*.'IsHidden' -eq [System.Boolean]$False ) -and ( $*.'IsSubWebOnly' -eq [System.Boolean]$False ) }

The Name property in above result includes the name of the folder in which to look for Onet.xml and the configuration setting inside the onet.xml file.